# What is wrong with this SQLAlchemy intersect?

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to intersect the below 2 queries, but I get this error:

> ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) (1064, "You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use near 'INTERSECT SELECT
>   user_checkpoint.id AS user_checkpoint_id, user_checkpoint.user_' at
>   line 4") 'SELECT anon_1.user_checkpoint_id AS
>   anon_1_user_checkpoint_id, anon_1.user_checkpoint_user_id AS
>   anon_1_user_checkpoint_user_id, anon_1.user_checkpoint_checkpoint_id
>   AS anon_1_user_checkpoint_checkpoint_id,
>   anon_1.user_checkpoint_date_added AS anon_1_user_checkpoint_date_added
>   \nFROM (SELECT user_checkpoint.id AS user_checkpoint_id,
>   user_checkpoint.user_id AS user_checkpoint_user_id,
>   user_checkpoint.checkpoint_id AS user_checkpoint_checkpoint_id,
>   user_checkpoint.date_added AS user_checkpoint_date_added \nFROM
>   user_checkpoint INNER JOIN checkpoint ON checkpoint.id =
>   user_checkpoint.checkpoint_id INNER JOIN user AS user_1 ON
>   user_checkpoint.user_id = user_1.id INNER JOIN facebook_user AS
>   facebook_user_1 ON facebook_user_1.id = user_1.facebook_user_id INNER
>   JOIN friend_connection ON friend_connection.fb_user_to =
>   facebook_user_1.id INNER JOIN facebook_user ON facebook_user.id =
>   friend_connection.fb_user_from INNER JOIN user ON
>   user.facebook_user_id = facebook_user.id \nWHERE user.id != %s AND
>   checkpoint.creator = user_1.id AND checkpoint.demo = %s INTERSECT
>   SELECT user_checkpoint.id AS user_checkpoint_id,
>   user_checkpoint.user_id AS user_checkpoint_user_id,
>   user_checkpoint.checkpoint_id AS user_checkpoint_checkpoint_id,
>   user_checkpoint.date_added AS user_checkpoint_date_added \nFROM
>   user_checkpoint INNER JOIN checkpoint ON checkpoint.id =
>   user_checkpoint.checkpoint_id \nWHERE checkpoint.creator != %s AND
>   checkpoint.demo = %s) AS anon_1 ORDER BY checkpoint.date_created DESC
>   \n LIMIT %s' (185L, 0, 185L, 0, 1)

```
    #get checkpoints from users with friends
    FriendUserCheckpoint, FriendFacebookUser, FriendUser = aliased(UserCheckpoint), aliased(FacebookUser), aliased(User)
    q = (db.session.query(UserCheckpoint).
         join(Checkpoint, Checkpoint.id == UserCheckpoint.checkpoint_id).
         join(FriendUser, FriendUser.id == UserCheckpoint.user_id).
         join(FriendFacebookUser, FriendFacebookUser.id == FriendUser.facebook_user_id).
         join(FriendConnection, FriendConnection.fb_user_to == FriendFacebookUser.id).
         join(FacebookUser, FacebookUser.id == FriendConnection.fb_user_from).
         join(User, User.facebook_user_id == FacebookUser.id).
         filter(User.id != user_obj.id).
         filter(Checkpoint.creator == FriendUser.id).
         filter(Checkpoint.demo == False)
         )

    #get checkpoints from users without friends
    p = (db.session.query(UserCheckpoint).
         join(Checkpoint, Checkpoint.id == UserCheckpoint.checkpoint_id).
         filter(Checkpoint.creator != user_obj.id).
         filter(Checkpoint.demo == False)
         )

    w = q.intersect(p)

    return w.order_by(desc(Checkpoint.date_created)).limit(limit).all()
```

How can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your query is the `order_by`: you try to order by the column which is not in your query. Your resulting `SQL` query looks like this:

```
SELECT anon_1.col1, anon_1.col2, ...
FROM (
    SELECT  <UserCheckpoint columns>
    FROM    UserCheckpoint
    ... (joins, filters etc)


    INTERSECT

    SELECT  <UserCheckpoint columns>
    FROM    UserCheckpoint
    ... (joins, filters etc)
) anon_1
ORDER BY checkpoint.date_created DESC -- @note: here is the problem
```

As you can see, the outer query does not have a `checkpoint` table in its list of source tables (which contains only one *table* `anon_1`). Remove the `order_by`, and I assume your query will work.

If you need order_by, then change queries to return also the `date_created` column, order the results, and get rid of that column later:

```
q = (db.session.query(UserCheckpoint, Checkpoint.date_created).
...
p = (db.session.query(UserCheckpoint, Checkpoint.date_created).
...
return [uc for (uc, _) in w.order_by(desc(Checkpoint.date_created)).limit(limit).all()]
```